# User defined variable is blank when just set

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to use PDO to set a mysql user define variable to use in triggers to properly identify the actual user that did the change.

This is what i tried in the login script after the section that has validated the login attempt:

```
//$sessionsql = "SET @app_user_name = ".$username.";";
$sessionsql = "SET @app_user_name := ".$username.";";
$setquery = $dbh->prepare($sessionsql);
$setquery->execute();

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT @app_user_name AS UName");
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($results as $result)
{
echo "<script>alert('UDV:".$result->UName."');</script>";
}
```

but it just returns blank?

Any pointers?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: I only did the second as the insert into the table failed because i changed the trigger to use @app_user_name instead of USER() so I added the 2nd query to confirm the UDV was actually set when it clearly isn't. So ignore the 2nd execute. How do I ensure the 1st sets the UDV? Thanks

Comment: `SET @app_user_name := ?` is the proper way to do this, then `execute([$username])`. The `;` is not necessary.

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is not true, the session is the same

Comment: @martin your code works for me, as it obviously should. are you sure $username is set?

Comment: Yes $username is set as this code is inside a block that verifies the actual user logging in is valid. Also did an echo before the SET line for sanity sake and it is set. So I wonder why $result->UName is blank

Comment: I also tried to use mysqli_query but the whole site uses PDO. This didn't set the UDV either?:   $sessionsql = "SET @app_user_name := ".$username.";";
    mysqli_query(sessionsql);

Comment: BTW this is on localhost with XAMPP, obviously need to test it locally first to prove the UDV is set for use within triggers, before changing all the triggers on both environments